# how to send some String value to ios real device clipboard using appium?

Tags: java, ios, appium

I've searched over the topics regarding this issue and can't find any solution that can help me with this especially with **java client 8** + **appium v 2.x** !

i'm trying to get the text from my test class for ex. `hello` and try to past it into the **iOS** clipboard but unfortunately it seems the value is `null` or `empty` string ...

I'm using the following code language : **java** + selenium framework

all other topics regarding this issue is mentioning to use the following command :
https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/clipboard/set-clipboard/

> ```
> driver.setClipboard("label", ClipboardContentType.PLAINTEXT, base64Content);
> driver.setClipboardText("happy testing");
> ```

the previous command is not working with new `Appiumdriver/driver` since it's using java client 8 the method `setClipboard` is not listed there !

- i tried the way they said to put the app in **foreground** but is not working for new `appium 2.x` + `java client 8` since the most of the methods has been  deprecated

> Set the content of the system clipboard (For iOS 15+ real devices)
> Apple security preferences require the WebDriverAgentRunner
> application to be in foreground in order to set the system clipboard
> content. Consider using Activate App and Background App to change the
> foreground application. Activate App command cannot launch the
> WebDriverAgent properly on some environments. It depends on XCTest
> framework by Apple. Then, you should launch the WebDriverAgent using
> its Springboard's application icon. Follow the example below. 1. Open
> Springboard, @driver.activate_app 'com.apple.springboard'. 2. Find the
> WDA icon with @driver.find_element :accessibility_id,
> 'WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner' (It should be visible on the screen) and
> click it. 3. Call the get clipboard API. 4. Open the application under
> test with the Activate App.

- another way that i've tried :
  [How to use setClipboardText on Appium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674841/how-to-use-setclipboardtext-on-appium-java)

> ((HasClipboard) driver).setClipboardText(“happy testing”);

still not sending any values !

- tried this soultion :
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592022/20274854

```
 StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(theString);
 Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
 clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
```

it's working on when i paste the text from my **Mac** clipboard but still not sending any values to **iOS** !

plz can anyone help me with this ?

**NOTE:** i tried all the previous solutions but nothing are working with new `Appium 2.x` + `java client 8`

Comment: Did you try starting the WDA from the Springboard as described or only using `driver.activateApp`?

Comment: thank yo it's working now my problem was how to open springboard app and i found that it's `Springboard is the internal function that launches apps when you tap on their icon on the Home screen. You can’t see it, but you use it every time you launch an app or switch apps` my problem was solved thanks @drunkencheetah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem has been solved

- **solution is** :

https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/clipboard/set-clipboard/

++ `Springboard is the internal function that launches apps when you tap on their icon on the Home screen. You can’t see it, but you use it every time you launch an app or switch apps`